# Preserve Permissions when adding files to a Samba share

Tags: permissions, samba, mac, zfs

I asked this over at superuser already but didn't get much input on it.

I have a Mac (El Capitan 10.11.6) client that is connected to an Ubuntu server (18.04 LTS) running Samba, sharing a ZFS pool. Everything works great, except that whenever I add a file to the server, the permissions are changed.

For example, here's foo.txt on the mac:

```
$ ls -l foo.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 leetbacoon  staff  160 Feb 21 15:37 foo.txt
```

When it is clicked and dragged to the server, the server copy changes the attributes:

```
$ ls -l /Volumes/SMB\ Share/foo.txt
-rwx------  1 leetbacoon  staff  160 Feb 21 15:37 /Volumes/SMB\ Share/foo.txt*
```

Copying the file from the server back to my Mac retains those permissions:

```
$ ls -l ./Copied\ From\ Server/foo.txt
-rwx------  1 leetbacoon  staff  160 Feb 21 15:37 ./Copied\ From\ Server/foo.txt*
```

I want to have the file permissions retained when copying to the server, i.e.:

```
$ ls -l /Volumes/SMB\ Share/foo.txt
-rw-r--r--  1 leetbacoon  staff  160 Feb 21 15:37 /Volumes/SMB\ Share/foo.txt
```

All the `ls -l` commands were executed on the Mac client.

Comment: @Podesta tried that and the file it did it again, turned the file into `-rwx------`

Comment: even just to test, tried `chmod 777 /Volumes/SMB\ Share/foo.txt` and still only gave me `-rwx------`

Comment: @Podesta something else really strange is the fact that when i ssh into my server and do `ls -l` i see `foo.txt`'s permissions are `-rwxr--r--`. whaaaa??? `chmod 777 foo.txt` on the server changes it on the server to `-rwxrwxrwx`, but on the Mac i still see the `-rwx------`

i'll try out your suggestions shortly

Comment: @Podesta i'm wondering if it is my smb.conf that's at fault, too. here's a copy of it in its entirety: https://pastebin.com/raw/sKzSmPx9

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Podesta, but neither work :-( i tried the first, then the second, then both, every time doing the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What happens when you insert the following two lines in the share definition in smb.conf:

```
ea support = yes
vfs objects = catia fruit streams_xattr
map archive = No
```

And restart smbd:

```
sudo service smbd restart
```

Comment: Thank you, but it didn't change :-(

Comment: Did you disconnect from the samba server and reconnect after adding the two lines?

Comment: Oops, forgot to do that. It works nice now, however when moving a file over that is `-rwxrwxrwx` it changes it to `-rw-rwxrwx`

Comment: I added another line in my post that you need to add to the [SMB Share] share definition in smb.conf. Remember to restart smbd and disconnect and reconnect to the server in Finder.

Comment: Working beautifully, thank you very much! Morbius also discussed this here: https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2414960

Comment: Morbious1 - not sure if you saw on ubuntu forums but i am nearly complete with this, just stuck on 1 last thing. if i copy, for example, **foo.7z** to the server with finder, then delete it on the server, Finder still thinks its there, says: **The operation can’t be completed because an item with the name “foo.7z” already exists.** I believe SMB isn't syncing. Do you know of any way to fix? Thank you very much.